# Segfault in emitted IR For `printf` call

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I would like to use the system `printf` to be able to print a single integer from the programming language I'm writing a compiler for, as in `print(3)`. I am running into a segfault when executing the compiled IR.

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35539748/5692730), my code is

```
#include "llvm/ADT/APInt.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace llvm;

static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);

int main() {
  static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;
  TheModule = std::make_unique<Module>("inputFile", TheContext);
  std::vector<Type *> Nats(1, Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));
  FunctionType *PNFT =
      FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext), Nats, false);
  Function *PNF = Function::Create(PNFT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "printf",
                                   TheModule.get());
  for (auto &Arg : PNF->args()) {
    Arg.setName("x");
  }
  FunctionType *mainType = FunctionType::get(Builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
  Function *main = Function::Create(mainType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main",
                                    TheModule.get());
  BasicBlock *entry = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", main);
  Builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);

  std::vector<Value *> printArgs;
  printArgs.push_back(ConstantInt::get(TheContext, APInt(32, 20)));
  Builder.CreateCall(TheModule->getFunction("printf"), printArgs);
  Builder.CreateRet(ConstantInt::get(TheContext, APInt(32, 0)));

  TheModule->print(llvm::outs(), nullptr);
}
```

I compile this with `` clang++ `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all` test.cpp ``

This outputs the LLVM IR

```
; ModuleID = 'inputFile'
source_filename = "inputFile"

declare i32 @printf(i32)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i32 @printf(i32 20)
  ret i32 0
}
```

which I  put into a file `test.ll` and compile as `clang test.ll`. I threw the segfaulting code into `lldb` and found that the code segfaults in `strchr`:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x14)
  * frame #0: 0x00007ffff7f300fc libc.so.6`__strchrnul_avx2 + 28
    frame #1: 0x00007ffff7e38a53 libc.so.6`__vfprintf_internal + 163
    frame #2: 0x00007ffff7e25a2f libc.so.6`_IO_printf + 175
    frame #3: 0x000055555555514b a.out`main + 11
    frame #4: 0x00007ffff7df5002 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 242
    frame #5: 0x000055555555506e a.out`_start + 46
```

I don't think the problem is with compiling the IR, because in my actual code (that is, not the MVE I've shown above) I'm emitting object code directly using a pass (as suggested in [part eight](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl08.html) of the kaleidescope tutorial) and still experiencing the same issue. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: The [first argument is printf is a string pointer](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). Your code is equivalent to `printf((char*)20));` and strchr dies because there's no string at address 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @arnt's comment, I found [this resource](https://the-ravi-programming-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ravi-jit-initial.html) which lead me to modify my program to the following:

```
#include "llvm/ADT/APInt.h"
#include "llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace llvm;

static LLVMContext TheContext;
static IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);

int main() {
  static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;
  TheModule = std::make_unique<Module>("inputFile", TheContext);

  std::vector<llvm::Type *> args;
  args.push_back(llvm::Type::getInt8PtrTy(TheContext));
  llvm::FunctionType *printfType =
      llvm::FunctionType::get(Builder.getInt32Ty(), args, true);
  llvm::Constant *printfFunc = Function::Create(
      printfType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "printf", TheModule.get());

  /*begin codegen for `main`*/
  FunctionType *mainType = FunctionType::get(Builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
  Function *main = Function::Create(mainType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main",
                                    TheModule.get());
  BasicBlock *entry = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", main);
  Builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);

  std::vector<Value *> printArgs;
  llvm::Value *formatStr = Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("%d\n");
  printArgs.push_back(formatStr);
  printArgs.push_back(ConstantInt::get(TheContext, APInt(32, 20)));
  Builder.CreateCall(TheModule->getFunction("printf"), printArgs);
  Builder.CreateRet(ConstantInt::get(TheContext, APInt(32, 0)));

  TheModule->print(llvm::outs(), nullptr);
}
```

This emits the following IR:

```
; ModuleID = 'inputFile'
source_filename = "inputFile"

@0 = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00", align 1

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %0 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @0, i32 0, i32 0), i32 20)
  ret i32 0
}
```

which works as expected.